# I can't work out why this Laravel API keeps returning a 404

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, axios

I have this controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Assetgroup;
use App\Models\Asset;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class AssetgroupController extends Controller
{
    
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['jsonvalidation:CreateAssetGroupResource'])->only('store');
        $this->middleware(['jsonvalidation:CreateAssetGroupResource'])->only('update');
    }
   
    public function update(Request $request, Assetgroup $assetgroup, Asset $asset = null)
    {
        **********


    }
```

This route in api.php

```
Route::apiResource('/assetgroups', 'API\AssetgroupController');
```

And it's being called fromt his axios request

```
Axios.put(`${API_URL}assetgroups/${division.id}`, {
            added
        }).then(r => {
            // DETECT ERROR

            toast('Users assigned!', {
                type: toast.TYPE.SUCCESS,
                autoClose: 2500
            });

            this.setState({
                added: [],
                selectedUsers: r.data.selected_users,
                saving: false,
                users: r.data.users
            });
        });
```

I am new to laravel, and I cannot work out why this isn't working. The browser returns a

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/assetgroups/22
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: A couple things to check; is your api group under the api prefix, is the asset group with the ID 22 soft deleted?

Comment: Yes, the API group is under 'api/' and the assetgroup does not have a soft delete column in the table. I can access it with a "Get" request from the same contorller/route in the 'index()' method.

Comment: You're using axios. Is it configured to place laravel's csrf token in the header of its requests?I think by default this was in resources/js/app.js or bootstrap,js. Also, are you doing some validation in the update method? Can you post the code of that method as well as the jsonvalidation middleware?

Comment: It wont let me post the code as it's too long. I've stuck the controller here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/84ece820997985d6cf6d42932434ce2becd09db1

Comment: I'm not sure about the csrf token, I'm a bit out of my depth here.

Comment: {
    "id": "https://thefleetoffice.com.au/CreateAssetGroupResource.schema.json",
    "schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "CreateAssetGroupResource.json",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "description": "The display name for this Asset Group.",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "maxLength": 64,
            "minLength": 1
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

change this :

```
Axios.put(`${API_URL}assetgroups/${division.id}`, {
```

to this and try:

```
Axios.put(`${API_URL}/assetgroups/${division.id}`, {
```